# Chart - Scale between 2 Numbers

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to create a chart but having problems in generating numbers(as my yAxis labels)

For example, **Lowest = 1.050130**, **Highest = 1.050220**

I want to generate numbers from highest to lowest value so that I can label it to my yAxis labels(**10 maximum labels**)

[image: graph]

Is there a way I can have a function that can return these values as an array?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `(Highest-lowest)/(Maxlabels-1)`

Comment: Thanks @Mahi. It worked like a charm!

Comment: lol i did nothing man . i don't even know which chart you are using .

Comment: your comment was helpful. I didn't use any chart library, I was trying to make my own chart

Answer (score 0):

```
function(start,end,steps){
    var vals = [];
    for(var i = []; i < steps; i++)
        vals.push(start+((end-start)/(i / (steps - 1))));
    return vals;
}
```